# How to return scrollbar in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, scrollbar, show

I want to fix scrollbar in popUp window,but unfortunately fix it in my other pages!
Please,tell me- how to return scrollbars in Sharepoint 2010.

When i want to fix scrolls- use :

```
 function FixRibbonAndWorkspaceDimensions() {
    ULSxSy:;
    g_frl = true;
    var elmRibbon = GetCachedElement("s4-ribbonrow");
    var elmWorkspace = GetCachedElement("s4-workspace");
    var elmTitleArea = GetCachedElement("s4-titlerow");
    var elmBodyTable = GetCachedElement("s4-bodyContainer");

    if (!elmRibbon || !elmWorkspace || !elmBodyTable) { return; }
    if (!g_setWidthInited) {
        var setWidth = true;
        if (elmWorkspace.className.indexOf("s4-nosetwidth") > -1)
            setWidth = false;
        g_setWidth = setWidth;
        g_setWidthInited = true;
    }
    else { var setWidth = g_setWidth; }
    var baseRibbonHeight = RibbonIsMinimized() ? 44 : 135;
    var ribbonHeight = baseRibbonHeight + g_wpadderHeight;

    if (GetCurrentEltStyle(elmRibbon, "visibility") == "hidden") { ribbonHeight = 0; }
    // Override default resizing behavior
    // -- adds padding to the top of the "s4-workspace" <div> if the ribbon exists and has content
    // -- allows the ribbon to be positioned using CSS instead of JavaScript (more accessible)
    // -- checks to see if the page is inside a "no-ribbon" dialog
    var elmRibbonContainer = GetCachedElement("RibbonContainer");
    if (elmRibbonContainer != null) {
        if (elmRibbonContainer.children.length > 0 && document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className.indexOf('ms-dialog-nr') == -1) {
            elmWorkspace.style.paddingTop = ribbonHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

i think ,that i have to write

Comment: i try to delete tag scroll="no" in v4.masterpage. Restart iis (iisreset),but scrolls soes not shown.

Comment: in chrome i can scroll down by mouse,but in ie9-no.

Comment: Please don't tag your question "fix" unless you are talking about FIX protocol.

Comment: okey.i remove this tag.